# Paired T Test With a Class

Tags: sas

I have some data that look like this:

```
Date    Close   
12/31/2014  222.41  
12/30/2014  222.23  
12/29/2014  225.71
12/26/2014  227.82
12/24/2014  222.26
12/23/2014  220.97
12/22/2014  222.6
12/19/2014  219.29
12/18/2014  218.26
```

The date range covers two full years 2013 - 14.

I'd like to do a paired T Test on Close but I'm struggling with my syntax. Presumably I need to convert dates to years? Or do I? Each date in 2013 matches another date in 2014.

I could change my data in a csv and set it out like:

```
   Date  | 2013_Close | 2014_Close
    Jan 1|  101       |  204
    Jan 2| 105        |  210
```

But if I wanted to avoid that, is there a way to do a paired T-Test with the data as they are?

Here's what I tried but I received errors:

```
proc ttest data=tsla sides=2 alpha=0.05 h0=0;
class Date;
format Date year.;
var Close;
paired 2014*2013;
run;
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, (.
ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

But even then how would SAS know 2013 and 14? IN English I need to tell SAS to run a paired T Test on Close where the pairing is on Date for each year.

Does that make sense? How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do a paired T-test, I think you need to get your data to look like this:

```
DayofYear   Close2013 Close2014
365         222.41    222.26   
364         222.23    220.97   
363         225.71    222.6    
362         227.82    219.29   
361         222.26    222.41 
360         220.97    222.23
359         222.6     225.71
358         219.29    227.82
357         218.26    222.26
```

One way to do this would be to create a variable for `DayofYear`, then use `proc sql` to self join the 2013 part of the table to the 2014 part of the table like this:

```
proc sql;
select
  coalesce(t1.dayofyear,t2.dayofyear) as dayofyear,
  t1.close as close2013,
  t2.close as close2014
from
  (select * from tsla where year(date)=2013) t1
  full outer join (select * from tsla where year(date)=2014) t2
  on t1.dayofyear = t2.dayofyear
;
quit;
;
quit;
```

To run the test, I think you shouldn't need your `class`, `var` or `format` statements. Just the `paired close2013*close2014;` statement.

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment means. Are you saying this wouldn't work? if not, why?